# is my working correct? Vector equations and planes.

Tags: calculus

Is my working correct with regards to the following question? Any feedback is appreciated.

Question: Find a vector equation for the plane that passes through the points $A(1, 1,a),B(2, 0,−1)$ and $C(−2, 1,−1)$. If a has the value $−1$, what can you say about the plane?

Is my working correct?

Vector $BA = <-1 , 1, 1+a>$ and vector $CA=<3, 0, 1+a>$

A normal vector to the plane $ABC$ is the vector product

$$n=BA x CA =<1+a, 4(1+a), - 3> $$

A vector equation for the plane is

$$r.n = (2,0,-1).(1+a, 4(1+a), -3)
=5+2a$$

If $a=-1$ the plane has equation $r.(0,0,-3) = 3$

which has Cartesian equation $z=-1$ and this is a plane parallel
to the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your $r$ is ambiguous
A vector equation for the plane is 
$$
(r-r_0).n=(x-2,y-0,z+1).(1+a,4(1+a),-3)=0
$$
where $r=(x,y,z)$ and $r_0=(2,0,-1)$ are points on the plane. So
$$
(r-r_0).n=(x-2)(1+a)+4y(1+a)-3(z+1)=0
$$
If $a=-1$ then $z=-1$.